# When I nest text-shadow, how to inherit the color of the shadow?

Tags: css, box-shadow

I have text with such shadow effects applied.

```css
span.inner_text {
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px red;
}
```

```html
<span class="inner_text">It's a simple text</span>
```

---

**Q1.**
We used `text-shadow` for the parent element, as we needed to add shadows to this. Then the parent element `text-shadow` did not work. Why is this? And how can I nest shadows?

```css
p {
  text-shadow: 15px 15px 15px blue; /* blue shadow disappeared */
}

span.inner_text {
  text-shadow: 12px 12px 5px red;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="inner_text">It's a simple text</span>
</p>
```

---

**Q2.**

Next, I used `drop-shadow` for the parent element. Then the shadow of the `p` element disappeared. Why is this? And how can I nest shadows?

```css
div {
  filter: drop-shadow(30px 10px blue);
}

p.inner_text {
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px red; /* red shadow disappeared */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="inner_text">It's a simple text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the **Q1**, add some text inside `p` and you will better understand

```css
p {
  text-shadow: 15px 15px 15px blue; /* blue shadow disappeared */
}

span.inner_text {
  text-shadow: 12px 12px 5px red;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="inner_text">It's a simple text</span> some text here
</p>
```

The blue shadow applies to the text inside p but for the text inside span we consider the shadow of the span.

It behave exactly like `color`. Only **one** `text-shadow` is used.

```css
p {
  color:blue;
}

span.inner_text {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="inner_text">It's a simple text</span> some text here
</p>
```

If you want multiple shadows, they need to belong to the same property either on the parent or the child element since it's an inherited property. Simply pay attention to the order (The shadow effects are applied front-to-back: the first shadow is on top)

```css
p {
  text-shadow: 
    15px 15px 15px blue,
    12px 12px 5px red; 
}

span.inner_text {
 
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="inner_text">It's a simple text</span>
</p>
```

---

For the **Q2** you simply have a typo as you have no `p` element and you are targetting a `p` element:

```css
div {
  filter: drop-shadow(30px 10px blue);
}

p.inner_text {
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px red; 
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="inner_text">It's a simple text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The code of Q2 that you have corrected has surely worked in this case!

Actually, I had [such a code](https://jsfiddle.net/3gocdL96/). And it was necessary to add a new shadow to each of these shadows.

The code in [Q2 worked](https://jsfiddle.net/oade6p0y/) by including the `p` element in the `div` element and using the `filter` property.

I tried to nest Q1's `text-shadow` property, but this didn't work like Q2. And I thought that this is because the `text-shadow` property has properties like the `color` property.

It was very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

**CSS**

```
span.inner_text {
  text-shadow: 12px 12px 5px inherit;
}
```

Use the CSS `inherit` property value to inherit the property of parent color.

Comment: You are using an invalid value ... it's not working like you think, the parent shadow is  now the one applied because the one of the child is simply invalid